# Consume SSL Web Service using Domino 8.0.2

Tags: web-services, lotus, lotusscript

Working on a project where I need to consume a web service over HTTPS (SSL) using Domino 8.0.2.

Was able to create the script library to consume the web service.

Created a simple button to test consuming it with this code:

```
Use "AA-FEED"

Sub Click(Source As Button)
Dim ws1 As New IAccountService_n1
Dim r1 As New  ArrayOfValidSystem_n2

Set r1 = ws1.GetValidSystemsList()

End Sub
```

When called, Notes prompts for me to Cross Certify with your server, which I do.

That is to be expected.

Click on 'Cross Certify" button and then the web service is contacted and returns an error message:

"The Web Service IAccountService_n1 method GetValidSystemsList has returned a fault."

So...

The provider of the web serivce says when it is consumed in Java, they add certifier information to the soap header.

Not sure if the Cross Certify actions in Lotus would do equlivent in LotusScript.

Comment: Does it literally say "your server", or does it give the name of the server you are cross-certifying with?  I.e., is it asking you to cross-certify with a Domino server, or is it asking you to cross-certify with the web service provider's server?

Comment: It comes back with name of server - like this: CN=aafeed-ab.ab.test-dns.com/OU=For Intranet Use Only/OU=Info Sec/O=XXX XXXX/L=XXXXXX/ST=XXXXXXXXX/C=US.  It is the name of the web service providers server.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using SoapUI? Does it work there?

Comment: It does, but only after entering authentication information into the soap header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the WebService requires authentication, in your generated web service consumer code, add the following after the webservice initialize call:

```
Sub NEW
    Call Service.Initialize ("UrnDefaultNamespaceWSQueryService", ...
    'ADD THE FOLLOWING
    'set userid and password if required
    Call Service.SetCredentials("userid","password")
    'set SSL options
    Call Service.SetSSLOptions(NOTES_SSL_ACCEPT_SITE_CERTS + NOTES_SSL_ACCEPT_EXPIRED_CERTS)
```

Comment: Will give this a try.  Looks like it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Web services in LotusScript has a Java component to it when communicating (uses AXIS).

It might be that you have to put the certificate into the CACERTS. The following wiki article explains this.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Connecting_to_a_Domino_server_over_SSL_in_Java_using_a_self_signed_certificate._